# Splunk map With zipcode

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

I am new to Splunk. I want to create a map using zipcode or city. I used the below query to get zipcode and city:

```
index=*** "cf_foundation=p**" cf_app_name=o***| spath input=payload | stats values(addresses{}.zip) as zipcode,values(addresses{}.cityName) as city
```

Output for the above query is as follows:

```
zipcode   city
----------------
30346     Atlanta
60067     BOTHELL
98021     PALATINE
```

I would like to know how to plot the Splunk map using the above data. Kindly help me to do this.

Note: I don't have any latitude/longitude data.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get your own [KML file](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/kml/kml_zcta.html) installed with the zip codes to properly map them on a choropleth map. There are [other KML](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-kml.html) files you can get as well. See [this blog](https://www.splunk.com/blog/2015/10/01/use-custom-polygons-in-your-choropleth-maps.html) for more details.